# Symfony form type that allows to select items from the multiselect list multiple times

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using symfony 5.4.My form type builder looks like this:

```php
class CardType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('price', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'clay',
                    'stone',
                    'wood',
                    'gold',
                    'carpet',
                    'glass',
                    'papyrus',
                ],
                'multiple' => true,
            ]);
    }
}
```

This code allows me to build a multiselect expanded drop down, but it lets to select items in the drop down only once. And I want to select the same item multiple times, for example 2 clays, 2 wood and glass. Is there some way to implement it using standard symfony components?

Comment: How this component should be rendered? I don't think there's an HTML native component to do what you're trying to do, so there isn't a standard symfony type to reach your goal. You probably need a more complex form structure with sub-forms and multiple fields to select also the quantity

Comment: Can you not just create an *IntegerType* input for quantity?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972047/multiselect-list-with-quantity-option-for-each-item) might be of some use to you. You can run the code snippet to see..